# How can I recursively delete all .svn directories using Perl?

Tags: perl

What would a Perl script look like that would take a directory, and then delete all `.svn` directories in that directory recursively?

(No shell, cross platform)

Comment: It's a solved problem, apparently. Surprised Sinan didn't attack you personally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can (and probably should) use [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) in the first place.

Otherwise, use [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Find) and [File::Path::rmtree](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Path):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use File::Find;
use File::Path qw( rmtree );
use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile );

find(\&rm_dot_svn, $_) for @ARGV;

sub rm_dot_svn {
    return unless -d $File::Find::name;
    return if /^\.svn\z/;
    rmtree(catfile $File::Find::name, '.svn');
    return;
}
```

Comment: Does Path::Class come with standard installations?

Comment: No. But you can use `File::Spec` instead.

Comment: Great! thanks. For some reason I had to switch remove_tree with rmtree(), but after that it worked great.

Comment: The docs say *The rmtree() function provide the legacy interface of remove_tree() with a different interpretation of the arguments passed.* I am not sure what that means. I updated the posted solution to use `rmtree`. Also, now the script will do the right thing when no or multiple top directories are specified on the command line.

Comment: @PP You know it is highly annoying that you keep posting comments about me deriding you. For the record, I did not vote down your answer (now deleted). I pointed out that it was unnecessary to do all that work. Your revenge downvoting of my answer is amusing but also very much uncalled for.